# Best-selling books. Which part of speech is "best-selling" and why?

Tags: parts-of-speech

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_books

I was very confused and curious about why we use Active Voice instead of Passive Voice here. I mean, a book on its own can barely sell anything! People sell them.

They explained to me it's because the word "selling" is a noun in this situation.

But could someone explain it more explicitly? Why is it a noun? I have some trouble determining the part of speech of those -ING words. The situation is even worse in my case because we have "best-selling" rather than just "selling".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *They are our* [*best-selling books*].

"Selling" is not a noun. "Best-selling" is a compound adjective consisting of the adverb "best" as the first component and the gerund-participle **verb** "selling" as head.

"Best-selling" then modifies the noun "books".

Answer (score 1):

In the noun phrase “best-selling novel” the (only) noun is *novel*. And “best-selling” modifies it:

> ”Say, Bill, how well is your novel selling?”

> ”It’s selling better than any other!”

> ”Wow! It’s the best-selling novel?”

If *selling* were acting as a noun (a gerund) it would be naming the process or activity that happens as things are sold, as in “Selling books can be hard work.” Instead, it’s acting as a verb (a present participle), naming what’s being done to the book: the exchange for money. Compare to a similarly constructed phrase that involves a **past** participle: “best-**loved** novel.”

And by the way, in “How well is your novel selling?” as in “best-selling novel,” the verb “selling” is in the active voice. It’s an intransitive use of the verb “to sell.” Compare to, “Milk is selling for $4.95 a gallon,” or “Champagne sells well around the holidays.”